# Adding android fragment terminates the app

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am a newbie to Android development and I created a blank fragment, which has a textview by default. I tried to add the fragment to my main activity and I am getting following error:

Connected to process 3689 on device samsung-gt_i9300-32305248b97211f9
Application terminated.

Not getting any other exception reason.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context="com.ideasurge.winfertility.AccountActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/titleImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wftitleimage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fertilityTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Fertility Companion"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleImageView"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentPlaceholder"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fertilityTextView">

        <!-- Fragment will go here eventually, but it's not added in the layout -->

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is Java code:

```
 AccountFragment fragment = new AccountFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragmentPlaceholder, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

Comment: The above error does not really help what is the problem of the program, make sure you grab the error from the logcat/output instead.

Comment: Please provide error log here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a Fragment to a LinearLayout. In must be a FrameLayout in order for it to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Change you linearLayout to frameLayout . because Fragment is unable to add in LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can have fragments in a LinearLayout. even you can have multiple fragments in LinearLayout.

you can find some documentation help [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

The problem with your code is that because you didn't specify fragment class. so, it's unknown to the 'Activity' what to inflate.

Try something like this when you declare fragment in the layout.

```
<fragment
    class="com.atwork.demo.ListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

create referenced fragment class to inflate it on activity attach.

To attach multiple fragments to LinearLayout, you can find help in this SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23896198/7079337)

**TIP**

- considering it's your complete layout file, try to create a root Layout and then create subRoot Layouts as you want.
- declare the namespace in the parent layout.