# How to add fragments dynamically when the no. is not known before hand?

Tags: android

I want to add **n** no. of fragment A to the layout, based on a server response. All fragments have same UI design, but will contain different data.

Do i have to define multiple container for this ? Whats a better approach ?

```
  <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/your_placeholder"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </FrameLayout>
```

I need a vertical scrolling experience , previous fragment should be visible as i scroll

Comment: Are you familiar with ViewPager and  ViewPager Adapter ???

Comment: like in a tab layout ? this is within one screen -vertical  scrolling behavior

Answer (score 0):

I share some points regarding your requirements,hope its helpful for You;)

[1]. Create an **arraylist** of your **number of fragment** for Server data and **fragment name** and add your server response into it.

[2]. Use **viewpager** for set your fragment and **tablayout** to fragment selections.

[3]. Create an **adapterclass** of viewpager and use arraylist and set your fragment into viewpager using that adapter.

Let me any case of any query!

Comment: i think  a better approach is to do this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558070/cannot-add-multiple-fragments-to-linearlayout

Answer (score -1):

use this code to generate dynamic viewpagers

```
public class DynamicSeriesSeasonAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

int mNumOfTabs;

public DynamicSeriesSeasonAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs){
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return dynamicfrgament.addfrag();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}}
```

your dynamic fragment would be regular add this static to that

```
public static frgamentadd addfrag() {
    dynamicfrgament fragment = new dynamicfrgament();
    return fragment;
}
```

you can use dynamic fragment to add fragment dynamically

```
for (int k = 1; k <=amount; k++){
            tab.addTab(tab.newTab().setText("tabcount" + k));
          }
          adapter = new dynamicfragment(getSupportFragmentManager(),tab.getTabCount());
          viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this is how i've achieved this

Comment: but i need a vertical scrolling experience , a view pager doesn't provide this right ?

Comment: previous fragment should be visible as i scroll

Comment: You can use a ViewPager.PageTransformer  visit this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html  to give the illusion of a vertical ViewPager. To achieve scrolling with a vertical instead of a horizontal drag you will have to override ViewPager's default touch events and swap the coordinates of MotionEvents prior to handling them @Fone

Answer (score -1):

You can use the fragmentStatePagerAdapter and viewpager to add n no of fragments. 
this is what i used in my project, when no of tabs were not fixed.

```
FragmentHome fragmentHome;
private List<String> tabs;
      //View Pager fragments setting adapter class
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        Context context;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            this.context = context;
        }


 //"tabs" is the number of fragments you want to pass, that many tabs will be added.
        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            fragmentHome= new FragmentHome();
            int i = 0;

            while (i < tabs.size()) {
                    Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
                   //set args to pass
                    homeBrands.setArguments(args1);


                i++;
                return homeBrands;

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return tabs.size();
        }


        @Override
        public String getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabs.get(position);
        }

        public View getTabView(final int position) {
            View tab = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.tab_custom_text, null);
            TextView tv = tab.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
            tv.setText(tabs.get(position));
            return tab;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            // Causes adapter to reload all Fragments when
            // notifyDataSetChanged is called
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

    }
```

add the no of tabs you want to add here

```
 tabs = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {          
                            tabs.add(result.get(i));         
                }
```

lastly, set the paderadapter to viewpager.

```
private TabLayout tab_filter;
    final ViewPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(fragManager, mContext);
            viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
            for (int i = 0; i < tab_filter.getTabCount(); i++) {
                TabLayout.Tab tab = tab_filter.getTabAt(i);
                assert tab != null;
                tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));

            }
```